# CSV file with comma delimiter and quotes, but not on every line

Tags: python, csv

Having an issue with reading a csv file that delimits everything with commas, but the first one in the csv file does not contain quotes. Example:

```
Symbol,"Name","LastSale","MarketCap","IPOyear","Sector","industry","Summary Quote",
```

the code used to try and read this is as follows:

```
from ystockquote import *
import csv

with open('companylist.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in readCSV:
        print(row[0])
```

What I get is the following:

```
Symbol,"Name","LastSale","MarketCap","IPOyear","Sector","industry","Summary Quote",;
```

However, I just want to get all of the symbols from this list. Anyone an idea on how to do this?

***edit***

More data:

Symbol,"Name","LastSale","MarketCap","IPOyear","Sector","industry","Summary Quote",;

PIH,"1347 Property Insurance Holdings, Inc.","7.505","$45.23M","2014","Finance","Property-Casualty Insurers","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/pih",;

FLWS,"1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc.","9.59","$623.46M","1999","Consumer Services","Other Specialty Stores","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws",;

So my expected output would be:

```
Symbol
PIH
FLWS
```

This would happen if the csv.reader read my file as each of the rows as a seperate list, and within each of these lists all of the items (delimited by commas) would be their seperate values. (e.g. symbol would be the value of [0], "name" would be the value of [1], etc.)

I hope this clears up what I'm looking for

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the easy way out:

Replaced all of the

```
"
```

with *nothing* in my csv file, this made it so that the csv.reader could read the csv file normally again.

Answer (score 0):

If `print(row[0])` is giving you a list, it might be because each row of your csv file is being read in as a list.

try `print(row[0][0])` maybe?

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, it would give me only the letter "S" as a string from, of course, Symbol.